# How can I add a local repository I've been using to GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I have a repository I've been using through the command line and want to add it to Github desktop. However, every way I've found has me create a new repository on my actual Github account rather than link the repository I have to the local copy.

How can I establish the link from my local repository to the project on Github without creating a new repository on my account?

Answer (score 0):

Switch temporarly to the command line, and, in the root folder of your local repository, establish the link to your existing (hopefully empty) remote GitHub repository:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/<myExistingRepository>
git fetch
```

Then switch back to GitHub Desktop, and see if your local repository can push to the remote one.